# I can't log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts

Every time I try to login to www.stackexchange.com, it says it will redirect me, but it doesn't actually do it.

I am constantly stuck on this URL: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%253f_%253d1143850276&cdl=1`

[image: This is what I get when I try to login.]